# Creating link with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a link in JS that moves the person the page from where he has come from. Here is the code.

```
<script  language="javascript">
function Jump()
{
document.href=document.referrer;
}
</script>
```

Here is the html,

```
<a href="#" onclick="Jump();">Skip and Continue</a>
```

Now when the user clicks on the link, nothing happens. Please guide me where I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: try this: document.location.href=document.referrer;

Comment: maybe your referrer is empty

Answer (score 1):

how about using the below code to move back

```
 history.back();
```

Comment: add this code to see if the broswer you are using support referrer.   if( 'referrer' in document ) { 
    console.log(document.referrer);
}

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers will not use `document.referrer` for privacy reasons, especially if the referrer is from another domain.

Instead, try `onclick="history.go(-1)"` instead of your `Jump()` function.

Answer (score 0):

**It is better to bind a click listener than use `onclick`.**

Try changing it to this:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#">Skip and Continue</a>
```

And Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.location.href=document.referrer; //actually better as "history.back()"
}
</script>
```

Comment: `document.href` isn't a thing.

Comment: @sachleen Oh oops, copy/pasted. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

It is not document.href but window.location.href...

```
<script>
function Jump(){
    if(document.referrer)location.href=document.referrer;
    else history.back();
}
</script>
```

(If you used the jump to get to the current page, there is no referrer.)